# How can I add empty input fields with onClick function using Formik in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I want to add 4 empty inputText fields once button Add Person is clicked, which then needs to be filled and update values property. Those empty inputs supposed to be added to values.persons property which is an array of objects once addPerson()is called. I have some logic inside, but unfortunately nothing happens with this code

```
const data = [
  {
    luxmedType: {
      package: "Indywidualny",
      type: "Opieka standardowa",
      cost: 0
    },
    companyCost: 91.6,
    comment: null,
    persons: [
      {
        name: "Marian",
        lastName: "Kowalski",
        type: "współpracownik",
        cooperationForm: "B2B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    luxmedType: {
      package: "Rodzinny",
      type: "Opieka premium",
      cost: 559.1
    },
    companyCost: 0,
    comment: null,
    persons: [
      {
        name: "Ewa",
        lastName: "Kowalska",
        type: "partner",
        cooperationForm: null
      },
      {
        name: "Maria",
        lastName: "Kowalska",
        type: "dziecko",
        cooperationForm: null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    luxmedType: {
      package: "osobisty",
      type: "Opieka premium",
      cost: 1000
    },
    companyCost: 0,
    comment: null,
    persons: [
      {
        name: "Anna",
        lastName: "Michalska",
        type: "partner",
        cooperationForm: null
      },
      {
        name: "Maria",
        lastName: "Michalska",
        type: "dziecko",
        cooperationForm: null
      },

      {
        name: "Aleksander",
        lastName: "Michalski",
        type: "dziecko",
        cooperationForm: null
      }
    ]
  }
];

const initialValues = data;

export default function App() {
  const { values, handleChange, onSubmit, setValues } = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values)
  });

  const addPerson = () => {
    const persons = [...values.persons];
    persons.push({
      name: "",
      lastName: "",
      type: "",
      cooperationForm: null,
      id: Math.random()
    });
    setValues({ ...values,persons });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Luxmed</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {initialValues.map((object) => {
          let luxmedType = object.luxmedType,
            companyCost = object.companyCost,
            comment = object.comment,
            persons = object.persons;

          return (
            <div style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
              <InputText
                name="package"
                value={luxmedType.package}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <InputText
                name="type"
                value={luxmedType.type}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <InputText
                name="cost"
                value={luxmedType.cost}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <InputText
                name="companyCost"
                value={companyCost}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <InputText
                name="companyCost"
                value={comment || ""}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              {persons.map((person) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <InputText
                      name="package"
                      value={person.name}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <InputText
                      name="package"
                      value={person.lastName}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <InputText
                      name="package"
                      value={person.type}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <InputText
                      name="package"
                      value={person.cooperationForm}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <button>Remove</button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={() => addPerson()}>Add Person</button>

        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is also codesandbox for You if You wish
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-bose-x6qk9y?file=/src/App.js:1552-1553&fbclid=IwAR3Q6bnkVyCtox5hTCHaFibtKJ92huwkSDVHKPOSiTdoA743lURBq76Abq0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should iterate (map) values instead of initialValues
2. Every mapped item should have unique key (every object in value array as well as every person in persons array). Consider adding unique keys to objects itself.
3. Also you can pass reference to addPerson function instead of anonymous function onClick={addPerson} and in addPerson you will receive event as an argument and you should add event.preventDefault() in your function body to prevent re-loading of page when you click you button
4. Instead of using setValue and passing updated values as an object, use setValue with callback function setValue(oldValues => {/*...Do you update here and return updated values */}) when you need previous values in state update. This will guarantee that most up to date state is used.
5. Your values are not an object with person property of type array, but array of object each having property persons as an array. So I believe you want to add new object to an array of objects. Do not mutate current array, instead copy existing one. Then push new object with all properties luxmedType, companyCost, comment, persons. Push new person to newly added objects persons array.Then setValue with updated array of objects (use callback update as in 4th step).

Please try to correct code yourself and ask questions if something unclear so community can give you more hints and suggestions if you stuck.